# .NET Core Dependency Injection with inherited interface

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have `I1`, `I2` and Class `Foo` where `I2` inherits `I1` (`I2`:`I1`) and `I2` is implemented in `Foo`. I want to register a scoped dependency such that always returns the same `Foo` object when any of the interface is referred within a single scope.

I tried this using the following registrations, but it yield three different instances of `Foo` within the same scope:

```
services.AddScoped<Foo>();
services.AddScoped<I1, Foo>();
services.AddScoped<I2, Foo>();
```

My definitions are as follows:

```
interface I1
{
    GetData();
}
    
interface I2 : I1
{
    string Data { set; }
}

class Foo : I2
{
    private string myData;

    public string Data { set => myData = value; }

    public string GetData() => this.myData;
}
```

**Fuctionality use.**

```
class Bar
{
    private I2 _i2;
    public Bar(I2 i2) => _i2 = i2;

    public void SetData() => _i2.myData = "My Data";
}

class AnotherBar
{
    private I1 _i1;
    public AnotherBar(I1 i1) => _i1 = i1;

    public string GetData() => _i1.GetData();
}
```

`GetData()` from `AnotherBar` will return the same data which is set at Bar-`SetData()` during same scope?

Comment: You are registering 3 *separate* instances of `Foo`. They will *not* share a state. You can inject each one using `Foo`, `I1` and `I2`. Try injecting all 3 in to `Bar` and look at their values. They will all be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common pitfall to watch out for when using MS.DI. The pitfall is called [Torn Lifestyle](https://simpleinjector.org/diatl). In the case of MS.DI, each registration gets its own cache. That means that your three registrations:

```cs
services.AddScoped<Foo>();
services.AddScoped<I1, Foo>();
services.AddScoped<I2, Foo>();
```

Each have their own cache and their own instance. So that means the following assertions hold:

```cs
using (var scope = provider.CreateScope())
{
   Assert.AreSame(scope.GetService<I1>(), scope.GetService<I1>());
   Assert.AreSame(scope.GetService<I2>(), scope.GetService<I2>());
   Assert.AreNotSame(scope.GetService<I1>(), scope.GetService<I2>());
}
```

To fix this problem, you'll have to rewrite the registrations to the following:

```cs
services.AddScoped<Foo>();
services.AddScoped<I1>(c => c.GetRequiredService<Foo>());
services.AddScoped<I2>(c => c.GetRequiredService<Foo>());
```

In this case, each registration still has its own cache, but since the second and third request the original `Foo` service, this ensures all three registrations return the same instance within a single scope.

Comment: Thanks Steven, What you shared worked well scenario I shared. Much appreciated.