# Dependency Injection in abstract classes sharing the same inteface

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I have a bunch of abstract classes with the base inheriting from an interface, as such :

```
public abstract class ServiceBase<T> : IServiceBase
protected ServiceBase(IExtService1 extService1, IExtService2 extService2, IExtService3 extService3)

public abstract class ServiceA<T> : ServiceBase<T>
protected ServiceA(IExtService1 extService1, IExtService2 extService2, IExtService3 extService3) 
: base(extService1, extService2, extService3)

public abstract class ServiceAA : ServiceA<Type1>
protected ServiceAA(IExtService1 extService1, IExtService2 extService2, IExtService3 extService3) 
: base(extService1, extService2, extService3)

public abstract class ServiceAB : ServiceA<Type2>
protected ServiceAB(IExtService1 extService1, IExtService2 extService2, IExtService3 extService3) 
: base(extService1, extService2, extService3)

public abstract class ServiceB<T> : ServiceBase<Type3>
protected ServiceB(IExtService1 extService1, IExtService2 extService2, IExtService3 extService3) 
: base(extService1, extService2, extService3)

    public abstract class ServiceBA : ServiceB<Type1>
protected ServiceBA(IExtService1 extService1, IExtService2 extService2, IExtService3 extService3) 
: base(extService1, extService2, extService3)

    public abstract class ServiceBB : ServiceB<Type2>
protected ServiceAA(IExtService1 extService1, IExtService2 extService2, IExtService3 extService3) 
: base(extService1, extService2, extService3)
```

with DI setup like this :

```
...
builder.Services.AddScoped<IExtService1, extService1>
builder.Services.AddScoped<IExtService2, extService2>
builder.Services.AddScoped<IExtService3, extService3>
builder.Services.AddScoped<IServiceBase, ServiceAA>
builder.Services.AddScoped<IServiceBase, ServiceAB>
builder.Services.AddScoped<IServiceBase, ServiceBA>
builder.Services.AddScoped<IServiceBase, ServiceBB>
...
```

now I would like to have access to ServiceBA in ServiceA or, if not possible, in ServiceAA and ServiceAB, like this :

```
public abstract class ServiceA<T> : ServiceBase<T>
protected ServiceA(IExtService1 extService1, IExtService2 extService2, IExtService3 extService3, ServiceBA<T> serviceBA) 
: base(extService1, extService2, extService3)
```

But it seems that serviceBA in ServiceA isn't instanciated and is always null ...
How can I fix that?

Comment: Could it be that the dependency injection system cannot resolve `ServiceBA` because it was registered via the `IServiceBase` interface? Do you need all services to be registered under the same interface? Would it make sense to register your services with their concrete type instead of the interface?

Comment: but `ServiceBA` is not generic

Comment: Well I guess I could make different interfaces with an exact copy/paste of its content but ... seems a bit ugly though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your services are registered in the DI-container by their interface, not the implementation type, so the DI-container cannot retrieve the `ServiceBA` by its type. But you can register services not only by interface:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IExtService1, extService1>
builder.Services.AddScoped<IExtService2, extService2>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IExtService3, extService3>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IServiceBase, ServiceAA>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IServiceBase, ServiceAB>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IServiceBase, ServiceBA>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IServiceBase, ServiceBB>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ServiceAA>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ServiceAB>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ServiceBA>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ServiceBB>();
```

After that container can resolve the correct implementation for each service.

Another solution is to make a factory that can resolve a specific service by string or by another key and inject it instead of directly injecting service itself:

```
public enum ServiceType
{
    ServiceAA,
    ServiceAB,
    ServiceBA,
    ServiceBB
}

public interface IServiceFactory
{
    IServiceBase CreateService(ServiceType serviceType);
}

public class ServiceFactory : IServiceFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ServiceFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IServiceBase CreateService(ServiceType serviceType)
    {
        return serviceType switch
        {
            ServiceType.ServiceAA => _serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceAA>(),
            ServiceType.ServiceAB => _serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceAB>(),
            ServiceType.ServiceBA => _serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceBA>(),
            ServiceType.ServiceBB => _serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceBB>(),
            _ => throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid service type: {serviceType}")
        };
    }
}
```

After that you can register `ServiceFactory` in DI-container:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IServiceFactory, ServiceFactory>();
```

And use it to resolve a concrete service:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly IServiceFactory _serviceFactory;

    public SomeClass(IServiceFactory serviceFactory)
    {
        _serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        IServiceBase serviceAA = _serviceFactory.CreateService(ServiceType.ServiceAA);
        IServiceBase serviceAB = _serviceFactory.CreateService(ServiceType.ServiceAB);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI `builder.Services.AddScoped<IServiceBase, ServiceBB>(); builder.Services.AddScoped<ServiceBB>();` will result in different instances of `ServiceBB` if resolved directly or via class name.

Comment: Thank you, I went for the first solution for now as it is the fastest one, the factory seems indeed cleaner but would force me to do lot of refacto as I didn't show everything I have on my side in cde and unit tests.

Comment: One warning about Vadim's first code example; it has a subtle bug, which is called a [Torn Lifestyle](https://simpleinjector.org/diatl) in DI terminology. This happens in, for instance `ServiceAA`, because there are two separate registrations for `ServiceAA`, one by itself and one by its interface. This will result in two individual instances of `ServiceAA` within a single scope. This can lead to problems in case `ServiceAA` contains state. For a solution to this problem, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67484596/264697).