# Dynamically Injecting Generic Interfaces and Implementations in .NET Dependency Injection using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, reflection

I have a method (RegisterType) in my .NET (6,7,8) library that dynamically scans and registers services in the dependency injection container. It works well for non-generic services, but I'm struggling to adapt it for generic services.

Here's the existing method:

```cs
private static void RegisterType(IServiceCollection services, Type implementationType, ServiceLifetime serviceLifetime)
    {
        var implementedInterfaces = implementationType.GetInterfaces();
    
        if (implementedInterfaces.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var implementedInterface in implementedInterfaces)
            {
                services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(implementedInterface, implementationType, serviceLifetime));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(implementationType, implementationType, serviceLifetime));
        }
    }
```

It's working fine with all services and repositories

Now, I want to use this method to dynamically inject services like:

```cs
public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseModel
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseModel

public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
```

How can I handle such generic scenarios dynamically? I want to ensure that both non-generic and generic interfaces and implementations are registered correctly based on the specified lifetime.

**Update 1**

I've tried this:

```cs
 // Handle generic interface
 var genericArguments = implementedInterface.GetGenericArguments().Select(g => g.BaseType).ToArray();
 var constructedInterface = implementedInterface.GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType(genericArguments);

 // Handle generic type
 var genericTypeArguments = implementedInterface.GetGenericArguments().Select(g => g.BaseType).ToArray();
 var constructedType = implementationType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType(genericTypeArguments);

 services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(constructedInterface, constructedType, serviceLifetime));
```

but in case of BaseModel it's registering only the base model and with class only System.Object
for example if my service is directly using the model

```cs
public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : CarModel
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : CarModel
```

It's working but there is no benefit of Generic here

Comment: A generic type *needs* a generic type parameter. If you are dynamically scanning and registering types you need some way to define what types these can be. If your implementing class is also generic you should probably use attributes to define these types. You cannot register an "open" generic type, and you probably do not want to create registrations for all possible types.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but there's a bug in your `RegisterType`. This method leads to [Torn Lifestyles](https://simpleinjector.org/diatl) when registering components with more interfaces and lifetimes other than Transient. For a solution, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67472041/net-core-dependency-injection-with-inherited-interface).

Comment: I belive [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) library does what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Prolog , As I can see in Scrutor you have to specify every thing, the interface, the implementation and even the generic, I'm trying to do something more generic using the reflection, I saw the idea on SprintBoot you just have to add a filter on top of your services 
check this https://github.com/esamelzain/SuperInject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many days of searching, I found the solution by passing the GenericTypeDefinition coming from `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` into the service `ServiceDescriptor` constructor

Updated Code

```cs
       private static void RegisterType(IServiceCollection services, Type implementationType, ServiceLifetime serviceLifetime)
       {
           var implementedInterfaces = implementationType.GetInterfaces();

           if (implementedInterfaces.Length > 0)
           {
               foreach (var implementedInterface in implementedInterfaces)
               {
                   if (implementedInterface.IsGenericType)
                   {
                       // Handle generic interface
                       var openGenericType = implementedInterface.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                       services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(openGenericType, implementationType, serviceLifetime));
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(implementedInterface, implementationType, serviceLifetime));
                   }
               }
           }
           else
           {
               //Generic & Non-generic type without interface
               services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(implementationType, implementationType, serviceLifetime));
           }
       }
```

Still I Will Keep an eye on [this issue](https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/tornlifestyle.html) and this answer will be updated when fixed